# How to investigate data on Apache Camel Route?

Tags: java, routes, jboss, apache-camel, rhel7

My project is working on getting data from one system to another. We are using Apache Camel Routes to send the data between JBoss EAP v7 servers. My question is, is there a way to investigate what the content of the packages are as they come across different routes?

We have tried upping the logging but our files/console just get flooded. We have also tried to use Hawtio on the server to see the messages coming across the routes but have had no success identifying where our message is getting "stuck".

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What consumer endpoint are you using for your route and what sort of messages is it receiving?

Comment: Our endpoint is a RHEL 7 server, it is then processed from here further. The message it is receiving is basically just a string message

Comment: By consumer endpoint I mean the `from(endpointURI)` of your camel route that is the entry point for the exchange.

Answer (score 0):

You can use unit tests to test your routes locally and then either log contents of the exchange at specific points using adviceWith and weave methods.

With unit tests you can easily debug your routes in your favourite IDE even if you're running camel in something like Karaf or Red Hat fuse.

```java
package com.example;

import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Processor;
import org.apache.camel.RoutesBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.builder.AdviceWithRouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.component.mock.MockEndpoint;
import org.apache.camel.model.dataformat.JsonLibrary;
import org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport;
import org.junit.Test;

public class ExampleRouteTests extends CamelTestSupport {
    
    @Test
    public void exampleTest() throws Exception 
    {
        ContractDetails testDetails = new ContractDetails(1512, 1215);
        mockJDBCEndpoints();

        context.getRouteDefinition("exampleRoute")
            .adviceWith(context, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder(){

            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                
                replaceFromWith("direct:start");

                weaveByToUri("direct:getDetailsFromAPI")
                    .replace()
                    .to("log:testLogger?showAll=true")
                    .to("mock:api")
                    .setBody(constant(testDetails));

                weaveByToUri("direct:saveToDatabase")
                    .replace()
                    .to("log:testLogger?showAll=true")
                    .to("mock:db");
            }
        });

        MockEndpoint apiMockEndpoint = getMockEndpoint("mock:api");
        apiMockEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(1);

        MockEndpoint dbMockEndpoint = getMockEndpoint("mock:db");
        dbMockEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(1);
        
        context.start();

        String body = "{\"name\":\"Bob\",\"age\":10}";
        template.sendBody("direct:start", body);

        apiMockEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
        dbMockEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
    }  

    @Override
    protected RoutesBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
        return new RouteBuilder(){

            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                
                from("amqp:queue:example")
                    .routeId("exampleRoute")
                    .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, 
                        Person.class)
                    .to("direct:getDetailsFromAPI")
                    .process(new SomeProcessor())
                    .to("direct:saveToDatabase");
                    
                from("direct:saveToDatabase")
                    .routeId("saveToDatabaseRoute")
                    .to("velocity:sql/insertQueryTemplate.vt")
                    .to("jdbc:exampleDatabase");

                from("direct:getDetailsFromAPI")
                    .removeHeaders("*")
                    .toD("http4:someAPI?name=${body.getName()}")
                    .unmarshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, 
                        ContractDetails.class);
            }
        };
    }

    void mockJDBCEndpoints() throws Exception {

        context.getRouteDefinition("saveToDatabaseRoute")
            .adviceWith(context, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder(){

                @Override
                public void configure() throws Exception {
                    weaveByToUri("jdbc:*")
                        .replace()
                        .to("mock:db");
                }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isUseAdviceWith() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now for troubleshooting problems that do not occur with unit tests you can configure generic or route specific exception handling with [onException](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/exception-clause.html) and use [Dead letter channel](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/dead-letter-channel.html) to process and and store information about the failed exchange. Alternatively you can just use [stream](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.12.x/stream-component.html) or file component to save information about the exception and failed exchange in to a separate file to avoid flooding logs.